# Internet Explorer throwing error on getElementById

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble with some javascript which uses getElementById.  It works fine in FF, Safari and Chrome, but IE(8 - haven't tried others) bails out.

The relevant bit of html is a div called topnav:

```
  <div id="topnav">
   ... some HTML ...
  <div>
  <div id="sub_1" class="lowernav">
   ... some HTML ...
  </div>
  <div id="sub_2" class="lowernav">
   ... some HTML ...
  </div>
```

In my javascript, I want to find topnav.  The full code (up to where it bails) is this:

```
<script>

 window.onload = init();

 function init() {
  // Show current menu
  showCurrentMenu();
 }

 function showCurrentMenu() {
  hideMenus(); // Hide all menus and then show the current one
  topnav = document.getElementById('topnav');
  ... rest of code ...
 }

 function hideMenus() {
  var divlist = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(var ii=0; ii<divlist.length; ii++) {
   if(divlist[ii].className != divlist[ii].className.replace('lowernav','')) {
    divlist[ii].className += ' hidden';
   }
  }
 }
```

... then some other code it hasn't reached yet...

Am I doing something wrong here?  It may well be something really obvious, but for the life of me, I can't see it!  All advice is much appreciated.

ETA: Ok, here's the whole code, as it currently stands:

```
<script>
 window.onload = init;

 function init() {
  // Show current menu
  showCurrentMenu;
  // Attach 'onmouseover' event to main menu items
  topnav = document.getElementById('topnav');
  // Get all items in list
  var menulist = topnav.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var ii=0; ii<menulist.length; ii++) {
   menulist[ii].onmouseover = showMenu;
  }

  document.getElementById('mainHomeNav').onmouseout = restoreMenu;
 }

 function restoreMenu(e) {
  var targ;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.target) targ = e.target;
    else if (e.srcElement) targ = e.srcElement;
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
  if (targ.id == "mainHomeNav") {
   showCurrentMenu;
  }
 }

 function hideMenus() {
  var divlist = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
  for(var ii=0; ii<divlist.length; ii++) {
   if(divlist[ii].className != divlist[ii].className.replace('lowernav','')) {
    divlist[ii].className += ' hidden';
   }
  }
 }

 function showCurrentMenu() {
  hideMenus;
  topnav = document.getElementById('topnav');
  // Get all items in list
  var menulist = topnav.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var ii=0; ii<menulist.length; ii++) {
   if(menulist[ii].className != menulist[ii].className.replace('thisSection','')) {
    var thisid = menulist[ii].id;
    var thissubmenu = document.getElementById(thisid + '_sub');
    thissubmenu.className = thissubmenu.className.replace(/hidden/g,'');
   }
  }
 }

 function showMenu() {
  hideMenus;
  // show this menu
  var submenu_id = this.id + '_sub';
  var submenu = document.getElementById(submenu_id);
  submenu.className = submenu.className.replace(/hidden/g,'');
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is

```
window.onload = init();
```

This will call the init function immediately, and then use its return value as the page's onload function. You need:

```
window.onload = init;
```

which will call the init function only after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: +1 for the right answer. Easy mistake to make, and easy to miss when you're trying to debug.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem - I didn't have 'var' in front of 'topmenu'.

So instead of

```
topnav = document.getElementById('topnav');
```

it should have been

```
var topnav = document.getElementById('topnav');
```

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the following line:

```
window.onload = init(); // this will CALL init() and assign the return value
```

Since `init` doesn't return anything, `window.onload` will be `undefined`.

Now the reason for it not working in IE, but in other Browsers is that those other Browsers might already have parsed a part of the DOM and therefore the call to `showCurrentMenu` works.

But that could just as well break, since from a technical point of view the document is not guaranteed to be loaded, to fix that you have to assign the actual function reference to `window.onload` by doing:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I changed it and it's still giving the error.

Comment: @Sharon Then you have to show us more of the code, since right now, I can't make out any other error.

Comment: @Sharon, ah I see what you did there :) You removed all the `()` from the function calls, of course the will **no** longer get called, you only needed to remove them from the `window.onload` *assigment* since you're telling the script "make window.load point to the function init". But you in all the other cases you want to **call** the function, so you have to leave the `()` there. I would strongly suggest to you to read a good JavaScript tutorial like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide